# How to create a step through tutorial using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I essentially need to create a version of the following website using JavaScript and HTML5 instead of Flash:
http://www.chrisgates.net/irv/votesequence.html

I don't really know how to go about doing it. I have though about creating still images and using a JQuery slideshow viewer to click through them but that doesn't really seem "tutorial like". I have also thought about displaying the images on a button press and hiding the previous image but i don't know how to do this without having to refresh the page. Any ideas and tips will be very useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i think your way of thinking (the jquery part) sounds decent, if you did it manually with
JavaScript or jquery, either way, if you dont want the page to reload every time then all the content would be laid out the holding page, then hidden via css or with javascript then show on button click.

it doesnt seem that long so id keep it simple, lay it all out on the page, for example div 1/div 2 etc, then hide them with js not css, this way if they dont have it enabled, itll still show 1 by 1 on the page, theyll just have to scroll down manually.

then do simple click to display functions and call it a day.

or Jquery it and atleast have it be more fluid. itd be at least sexier?

Comment: Do you know of any decent JQuery plugins for the task? I've been searching but i can't find anything that is appropriate.

Comment: i guess itd depend on how you design it but, if you google up "jquery image slider" MANY options come up. pick on that best suits the one you have. like this one for example http://www.tn3gallery.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the images in an array, and draw the selected image to the canvas.